# How to show the following characteristic function is positive definite

Tags: characteristic-functions

Let $\phi$ is the characteristic function of a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, how can I prove $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}{\phi(t_i-t_j)\bar{\phi}(t_i-t_j)\xi_i\bar{\xi_j}}\geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\in\mathbb{C}$, and $t_1,\ldots,t_n\in\mathbb{R}$?

I already know the proof for $\phi$, but here we have two kernel functions. Can someone give me hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variable whose common characteristic function is $\phi$. Then the characteristic function of $X-Y$ is $t\mapsto \phi(t)\overline{\phi(t)}$ hence the non-negativeness of $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}{\phi(t_i-t_j)\bar{\phi}(t_i-t_j)\xi_i\bar{\xi_j}}\geqslant 0$ follows from the fact that a characteristic function is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Does your "non-negativeness" also means "positive-definite" in the sense of function?

Comment: I actually meant "positive semi-definite".

Comment: Not sure i understand your 'positive semi-definite'